# Convert a ISODate string to mongoDB native ISODate data type

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, isodate

My application generates logs in JSON format. The logs looks something like this :

```
{"LogLevel":"error","Datetime":"2013-06-21T11:20:17Z","Module":"DB","Method":"ExecuteSelect","Request":"WS_VALIDATE","Error":"Procedure or function 'WS_VALIDATE' expects parameter '@LOGIN_ID', which was not supplied."}
```

Currently, I'm pushing in the aforementioned log line as it is into mongoDB. But mongoDB stores the Datetime as a string (which is expected). Now that I want to run some data crunching job on these logs, I'd prefer to store the Datetime as mongoDB's native ISODate data type.

There are 3 ways I can think of for doing this :

i) parse every JSON log line and convert the string to ISODate type in the application code and then insert it. Cons : I'll have to parse each and every line before pushing it to mongoDB, which is going to be a little expensive

ii) After every insert run a query to convert the last inserted document's string date time to ISODate using

```
element.Datetime = ISODate(element.Datetime);
```

Cons : Again expensive, as I'm gonna be running one extra query per insert
iii) Modify my logs at generation point so that I don't have to do any parsing at application code level, or run an update query after every insert

Also, just curious, is there a way I can configure mongoDB to auto convert datetime strings to its native isodate format ?

TIA

EDIT:
I'm using pymongo for inserting the json logs

My file looks something like this :

{"LogLevel":"error","Datetime":"2013-06-21T11:20:17Z","Module":"DB","Method":"ExecuteSelect","Request":"WS_VALIDATE","Error":"Procedure or function 'WS_VALIDATE' expects parameter '@LOGIN_ID', which was not supplied."}

There are hundreds of lines like the one mentioned above.
And this is how I'm inserting them into mongodb:

```
for line in logfile:
    collection.insert(json.loads(line))
```

The following will fix my problem:

```
for line in logfile:
    data = json.loads(line)
    data["Datetime"] = datetime.strptime(data["Datetime"], "%Y-%M-%DTHH:mmZ")
    collection.insert(data)
```

What I want to do is get rid of the extra manipulation of datetime I'm having to do above. Hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: You control the application - why not generate the date as ISODate and store that from the start?

Comment: Thanks @AsyaKamsky . My application(s) generate the logs and store them as files on their particular server. These logs are moved to a central log storage server where from I push the logs to mongoDB. The log files have the time in ISODate format in string, but when I push the log to mongoDB, it takes in time data as a string.

Comment: You can reduce the number of inserts by using bulk inserts and appending the documents in an array and then inserting when the array has X entries.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you already have the answer... I would stick with:

```
for line in logfile:
    data = json.loads(line)
    data["Datetime"] = datetime.strptime(data["Datetime"], "%Y-%M-%DTHH:mmZ")
    collection.insert(data)
```

I had a similar problem, but I didn't known beforehand where I should replace it by a datetime object. So I changed my json information to something like:

```
{"LogLevel":"error","Datetime":{"__timestamp__": "2013-06-21T11:20:17Z"},"Module":"DB","Method":"ExecuteSelect","Request":"WS_VALIDATE","Error":"Procedure or function 'WS_VALIDATE' expects parameter '@LOGIN_ID', which was not supplied."}
```

and parsed json with:

```
json.loads(data, object_hook=logHook)
```

with 'logHook' defined as:

```
def logHook(d):
    if '__timestamp__' in d:
        return datetime.strptime(d['__timestamp__'], "%Y-%M-%DTHH:mmZ")
    return d
```

This *logHook* function could also be extended to replace many other 'variables' with *elif, elif*, ...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

*Also, just curious, is there a way I can configure mongoDB to auto convert datetime strings to its native isodate format ?*

You probably want to create a Python `datetime` object for the timestamp, and insert that using PyMongo. This is stored under the hood as the native date object in MongoDB.

So, for example in Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
object_with_timestamp = { "timestamp": datetime.now() }
your_collection.insert(object_with_timestamp)
```

When this object gets queried from the Mongo shell, an ISODate object is present:

`"timestamp" : ISODate("2013-06-24T09:29:58.615Z")`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on with what language/driver/utility you're pushing the log. I am assuming you're using *mongoimport*.

*mongoimport* doesn't support ISODate(). Refer to this issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5543  ISODate() is not a JSON format, hence not supported in *mongoimport*.

i) approach seems more efficient. ii) does two actions on mongo: insert & update. I had same issue while importing some log data into mongo. I ended up converting ISO 8601 format date to epoch format.

```
{"LogLevel":"error","Datetime":{"$date" : 1371813617000},"Module":"DB","Method":"ExecuteSelect","Request":"WS_VALIDATE","Error":"Procedure or function 'WS_VALIDATE' expects parameter '@LOGIN_ID', which was not supplied."}
```

Above JSON should work. Note that it is 64-bit not 32-bit epoch.

Comment: I'm using pymongo, with Python for pushing the logs. I have added a small code sample of how I'm doing it currently.

Comment: the issue you linked is not the correct issue - the correct one is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5675 and that one has been fixed.